# Javascript Canvas Gradient creates blurry color stops

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, gradient, linear-gradients

I have been trying to create a linear gradient with the HTML Canvas API. However, I want to integrate multiple "hard stops" into the gradient, to make for more immediate transitions between color groups. This is the code I have written that will generate a gradient using the Canvas API:

```html
<head>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
<head>

<canvas id='grad'></canvas>

<script>
    var colors = [
        'rgb(116, 78, 173)',
        'rgb(147, 141, 117)',
        'rgb(150, 145, 83)',
        'rgb(210, 212, 180)',
        'rgb(204, 207, 180)',
        'rgb(65, 91, 158)',
        'rgb(67, 97, 162)',
        'rgb(106, 208, 225)',
        'rgb(111, 214, 232)',
        'rgb(53, 213, 91)',
        'rgb(17, 213, 24)',
        'rgb(9, 94, 9)',
        'rgb(29, 104, 9)',
        'rgb(234, 210, 4)',
        'rgb(255, 226, 0)',
        'rgb(255, 128, 0)',
        'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
        'rgb(113, 0, 0)',
        'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        'rgb(255, 146, 255)',
        'rgb(255, 117, 255)',
        'rgb(225, 11, 227)',
        'rgb(178, 0, 255)',
        'rgb(99, 0, 214)',
        'rgb(5, 236, 240)',
        'rgb(1, 32, 32)',
        'rgb(1, 32, 32)',
        'rgb(1, 32, 32)'
    ]
    var values = [
        -30, -20,
        -20, -10,
        -10, 10,
        10, 18,
        18, 22,
        22, 35,
        35, 40,
        40, 50,
        50, 60,
        60, 65,
        65, 70,
        70, 75,
        75, 85,
        85,
        95
    ]

    var canvasElem = document.getElementById('grad');
    canvasElem.width = (window.innerWidth - 50);
    canvasElem.height = 100;
    var ctx = canvasElem.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElem.width, canvasElem.height);
    var grdt = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvasElem.width, 0);
    var cmax = values[values.length - 1];
    var cmin = values[0];
    var clen = colors.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < clen; i++) {
        grdt.addColorStop((values[i] - cmin) / (cmax - cmin), colors[i]);
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = grdt;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasElem.width, canvasElem.height);
</script>
```

However, if you zoom in on one of those hard stops, you will get a very blurry transition between colors, when it should be an instant change:

[image]

Here is the same gradient generated using CSS's `linear-gradient`:

```html
<head>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
</head>

<canvas id='grad'></canvas>

<script>
    var colors = [
        'rgb(116, 78, 173)',
        'rgb(147, 141, 117)',
        'rgb(150, 145, 83)',
        'rgb(210, 212, 180)',
        'rgb(204, 207, 180)',
        'rgb(65, 91, 158)',
        'rgb(67, 97, 162)',
        'rgb(106, 208, 225)',
        'rgb(111, 214, 232)',
        'rgb(53, 213, 91)',
        'rgb(17, 213, 24)',
        'rgb(9, 94, 9)',
        'rgb(29, 104, 9)',
        'rgb(234, 210, 4)',
        'rgb(255, 226, 0)',
        'rgb(255, 128, 0)',
        'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
        'rgb(113, 0, 0)',
        'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        'rgb(255, 146, 255)',
        'rgb(255, 117, 255)',
        'rgb(225, 11, 227)',
        'rgb(178, 0, 255)',
        'rgb(99, 0, 214)',
        'rgb(5, 236, 240)',
        'rgb(1, 32, 32)',
        'rgb(1, 32, 32)',
        'rgb(1, 32, 32)'
    ]
    var values = [
        -30, -20,
        -20, -10,
        -10, 10,
        10, 18,
        18, 22,
        22, 35,
        35, 40,
        40, 50,
        50, 60,
        60, 65,
        65, 70,
        70, 75,
        75, 85,
        85,
        95
    ]

    var canvasElem = document.getElementById('grad');
    canvasElem.width = (window.innerWidth - 50);
    canvasElem.height = 100;
    var cmax = values[values.length - 1];
    var cmin = values[0];
    var clen = colors.length;

    var gradColors = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < clen; i++) {
        var curPercent = (((values[i] - cmin) / (cmax - cmin)) * 100);
        gradColors += `${colors[i]} ${curPercent}%`;
        if (!(i == clen - 1)) { gradColors += ',\n' }
    }

    $('<style>')
        .prop('type', 'text/css')
        .html(`
        #grad {
            background: linear-gradient(
                to right,
                ${gradColors}
            );
        }`)
        .appendTo('head');
</script>
```

Here, if you zoom in, you get a perfect transition between colors:

[image]

Here is my question: **Is there any way that I can make a hard stop using a `canvas` gradient, without making the transitions blurry?**

To clarify, I do need to use `canvas` in this situation, because I will end up exporting it to `ImageData` using `ctx.getImageData()` to be used in a WebGL texture.

I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: First, you are not using a CanvasGradient here. You are setting the CSS background-image of a <canvas> element. You won't be able to read the pixel data of that gradient through `getImageData`. To do that you'd use `ctx.createLinearGradient()` to get a proper `CanvasGradient` that you'd use as the context's `fillStyle`. Then it's really unclear what your code is supposed to do. To create hard stops, you duplicate the next stop color at the previous position. So at the end you'll get something like [colorA-0, colorA-0.1, colorB-0.1, colorB-0.2, colorC-0.2, etc.

Comment: @Kaiido That is exactly what I’m doing - the issue is that it’s still creating a slight gradient. I am also indeed using createLinearGradient for the canvas section of my code.

Comment: No, this is not what your code is doing, log the results. Your code is doing [colorA-0, colorB-0.1, colorB-0.1, colorC-0.2, colorC-0.2, etc So between 0 and 0.1 it will interpolate between colorA and colorB.